# K8s pod ImagePullBackoff

Tags: kubernetes

created a very simple nginx pod and run into status `ImagePullBackoff`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  32m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned reloader/nginx to aks-appnodepool1-22779252-vmss000000
  Warning  Failed     29m                   kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp 52.200.78.26:443: i/o timeout
  Warning  Failed     27m                   kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp 52.21.28.242:443: i/o timeout
  Warning  Failed     23m                   kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp 3.223.210.206:443: i/o timeout
  Normal   Pulling    22m (x4 over 32m)     kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     20m (x4 over 29m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     20m                   kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp 3.228.155.36:443: i/o timeout
  Warning  Failed     20m (x7 over 29m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Warning  Failed     6m41s                 kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp 52.5.157.114:443: i/o timeout
  Normal   BackOff    2m17s (x65 over 29m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "nginx"
```

Checked network status:

- A VM in the same subnet can access "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest" and `telnet 52.5.157.114 443` successful.
- `docker pull nginx` successfully on the VM in the same subnet.
- `kubectl exec` into a running pod in the same cluster can `wget https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest` successfully.
  .
  What is the possible problem?

Comment: What is in your "image" yaml field of your pod?

Comment: What does `kubectl logs POD_NAME`command outputs?

Comment: Do you need authentication to this registry?

Comment: Since it is a very simple nginx pod, can you share the yaml manifest please? Or the command you are using to deploy this

Comment: Please add command/yaml file, you've used to create this pod

Comment: I'm using nginx to recreate the problem, so the image is nginx. I guess nginx shouldn't need any authentication, right?
I'm not using any yaml, I just used command to create the pod: kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Never --port=80

Comment: "kubectl logs nginx" doesn't output anything cause the pod has not been created yet due to ImagePullBackoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be firewall dropped the package.

Answer (score 1):

When I wget/curl or anything you want to access

```
https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest
```

It says

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/nginx","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

However this is because you need to be logged in to pull this image from this repository.

2 solutions:

The first is simple, in the image field just replace this url by `nginx:latest` and it should work

The second: create a [regcred](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Answer (score 0):

in your pod yaml , change `image : docker.io/library/nginx:latest` to `docker.io/nginx:latest`